# Is there a way to test if a URL is part of the current blog?

Tags: urls

In a scenario where, say, your plugin or theme has been given a URL. You want to know, is this URL a URL from this very blog? How would you test if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to use `url_to_postid( $url )`, which returns a "*ID of the post or page that resides at the given URL, or 0 on failure.*", https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid

But this doesn't work with archives, I think. To find out if the url is for an archive, you'd probably need to `explode()` the path and then do some kind of `get_term_by()` with the parts.

Perhaps a little less strict way would be to compare the url's host to your domain,

```
if ( false !== strpos( get_home_url(), parse_url( $some_url, PHP_URL_HOST ) ) ) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```
if ( parse_url( $some_url, PHP_URL_HOST ) === parse_url( get_home_url(), PHP_URL_HOST ) ) {
  // do something
}
```

But doing it this way, you wouldn't know, if the path was correct or not.